# ¿Cómo hago para sumar los valores de una columna en un treeview? (Python Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un Treeview, y necesito sumar los valores de unas 4 columnas, así como en excel, para guardar el total de cada columna, con su respectiva variable, pero no se como hacerlo.
Diseño de Treeview:

```
style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Roboto Mono', 8)) 
    style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Roboto Mono', 9, BOLD)) 
    self.grid1= ttk.Treeview(height=7, columns=("#0","#1","#2","#3","#4","#5"), style="mystyle.Treeview")
    self.grid1.place(x=130,y=280)
    self.grid1.column("#0",width=75,anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.heading("#0", text="Codigo", anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.column("#1",width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.heading("#1", text="Producto", anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.column("#2",width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.heading("#2", text="Precio", anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.column("#3",width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.heading("#3", text="Cantidad", anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.column("#4",width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.heading("#4", text="Subtotal", anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.column("#5",width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.heading("#5", text="ITBIS", anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.column("#6",width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.grid1.heading("#6", text="Total", anchor=CENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que buscas vamos a usar dos métodos:

- `set(item, columna)`: Con el método set del treeview puedes obtener el valor de una "celda" del treeview en forma de cadena.
- `get_children()`: Te permite obtener todos los items en un item especifico del treeview. Si no especificas el item, se obtienen todos los items de la raíz.

Usando estos dos métodos podrías obtener todos los items, iterar sobre dicha lista, obtener así el valor de cada celda y sumarlo a una variable.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
# Inicializo total con el valor 0
total = 0

# Obtengo la lista de items e itero con ella. La variable item almacenará el id del item que actualmente estamos visitando.
for item in tree.get_children():
    # Obtengo el valor de la "celda" cuyo item es item y cuya columna es "#0"
    # Como me devuelve el valor en forma de cadena, lo convierto al tipo que deseo. En este ejemplo va a ser un entero.
    celda = int(tree.set(item, "#0"))

    # Sumo el valor obtenido a la variable total
    total += celda
```